# Use get_posts() with 'post' and 'page' queries at the same time?

Tags: pages, get-posts

I'm trying to grab all posts which are 'posts' and not in category '3' and '5' and which aren't 'pages'. Is this possible to do using one single `get_posts()`? Because I'm querying both actual posts and pages at the same time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**`get_posts()`** function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) only returns *one post type at a time*. So if you query for `'post_type' => 'post'`, *by default* you won't get any Pages returned.

This should work:

```
<?php
$wpse53292_posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'exclude'   => array( 3, 5 )
) );
?>
```